# how i can add Add text at the beginning of each line?

Tags: linux, command-line, file

how i can add Add text at the beginning of each line?

for example:- i have file contain:-

```
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core 
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees 
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/2ds
```

i want it to become:-

```
svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core 
svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees    
svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/2ds
```

in other word i want to add "svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo" at the beginning of each line of this file

Comment: you need a shell script?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `awk`.

```
awk '{ printf "svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo"; print }' <filename>
```

If you want to modify the file in place, you can use `sed` with the `-i` switch.

```
sed -i -e 's_.*_svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo&_' <filename>
```

Comment: Wouldn't gawk '{print "svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo"$0}' <filename>  be simpler?

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" | sed "s/^/new text /"
```

Using `ex`:

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" | ex -s +"%s/^/foo bar /e" +%p -cq! /dev/stdin
```

Using `vim`:

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" | vim - -es +"%s/^/foo bar /e" +%p -cq!
```

Using shell:

```
printf "line1\nline2\n" | while read line; do echo foo bar $line; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ruby -pne 'sub(/^/,"svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo")' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
sed -i 's_._svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo_' <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done with Perl:

```
perl -pe 's#^#svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo#' input.file
```